# TYPO3 : Extension upgrade from version 7 to 9

Tags: upgrade, typo3-9.x

I just updated my TYPO3 site from 7.6.x to 9.5.x and I get error with a custom extension :

**Error :**

```
Call to a member function exec_SELECTquery() on null
```

I think my plugin is not compatible with TYPO3 9.5.x.

The error come from this line :

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery($select, $table, $where, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit);
```

How to edit this line to make it works with TYPO3 9.

Answer (score 2):

With TYPO3 9 the database interface `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` has beeen removed and the usage of `doctrine-dbal` is mandantory.

you can get more information along with some examples in the [chapter about migration in the manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html).